# Protected Route - how to stop logged in users to access the Login and Signup page ? REACT

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have found the solution, however I am not sure if that is completely correct:

I have divided Routes to Protected and Normal and I am passing user, path etc as props. And if the path equals to the client end-point i.e. /auth/login and /auth/signup user will be redirected to the homepage. And if there is no user in props route will be returned.

It seems to work fine, but I am trying to double check whether that is a complete solution and there is no way around it to still access those routes as logged in user.

```
const NormalRoute = ({
  user,
  exact,
  to,
  path,
  component,
  ...componentProps
}) => {
  const Component = component;

  if (user && (path === PATHS.LOGIN_PAGE || path === PATHS.SIGNUP_PAGE)) {
    return <Redirect to={PATHS.DASHBOARD_PAGE} />;
  }

  return (
    <Route
      exact={exact}
      path={path || to}
      render={(props) => (
        <Component {...componentProps} {...props} user={user} />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Thanks

Comment: If you never render the route, they can not see the route. If getting the user is an async action they may be able to first see the Route until the user is retrieved and then they will be redirected. It depends on how you are retrieving your user and when you are rendering your routes.

Comment: Thanks, regarding your reply I am creating session when the user logs in and then passing user data including back to frond in headers. Than in main app.js that renders all the files I am running component did mount and if there is a session I set user to user from headers. Then I pass this data in props to login and signup Routes that have the code above.